# cabal hell with dependencies of ghc-baked in packages

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have the following instance of cabal hell:

(with ghc-7.8.3 built from source on x86_64 GNU/Linux,
and user-install: True in .cabal/config)

1) at some time, transformers-0.4.0.0 was installed (in user space, shadowing (?) transformers-0.3 from the global space)

2) later, several libraries pick transformers-0.4

3) then, I install hint, which depends on ghc, which depends on transformers-0.3, and which cannot be changed, since ghc is hard-wired.

result: I cannot use libraries from 2) and hint in one project.

As a work-around, I am putting `constraint: transformers installed` in .cabal/config, and rebuild. Is there a better way to handle this situation - or to avoid it in the first place?

Comment: Use `cabal sandbox` as often as possible, and only install binaries like `happy`, `alex` globally. Even better, also install those in a sandboxed environment and put a link to `~/bin/` (or to another directory in your `$PATH`)

Comment: How would that change the above? Are you implying that the sandbox mechanism would have figured out on its own to not update transformers? How could it?

Comment: If you use cabal in a sandbox, you don't change the global packages.

Comment: yes (global = user-global). The problem is that I'd need to build 2) and 3) in the same sandbox, at the same time? but in my case, both are large projects.

Comment: Besides cabal sandboxes (introduced in version 18) there is also another nice package for isolated environments called [hsenv](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsenv), suitable esp. for cases with multiple ghc versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way to handle this situation.

No, your approach is sensible.

> or to avoid it in the first place?

Tricky. Most people do not build stuff depending on `ghc`, so for them it makes sense to upgrade `transformers` etc. Therefore, your constraint is not a suitable default.

As Zeta writes: Sandboxes can help. If you had used sandboxes for your installations in (2), and used another sandbox for whatever tries to use both hint and (2), then it would simply build these dependencies dedicated for whatever you are building.

This comes at the expense of not sharing any space or build-time between the various things you are doing.